# FTP Upload in a Cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

i have made a Mac OS application, that i was wanting to add a feature to. The user adds data to a NSTableView, then the data is compiled into a `.xml` file. What i want to do is upload that `.xml` file to a server, and overwrite the existing file named that. How would i do this? I have hear of Apple's Version, but it is for iPhone and looks a bit confusing. I am only 16, and was wanting to know if there is an easier way of uploading a file to a remote server. Thanks!

Comment: I typically upload a file using a web service.

Comment: Well, yea, but what about an FTP client? It is a software. Is there a way i can upload a file through my software?

Comment: Please come up with an attempt and ask us how to fix it to make this a more constructive question. To point you in a direction that could work, a server can be configured to accept a PUT or POST command to overwrite a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least a couple built-in ways to do ftp'ing from an OSX application.

Apple has a [useful article available here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFFTPTasks/CFFTPTasks.html) which shows how to do uploading. I'm not certain (it may be dependent on server implementation) if an upload overwrites a previous file or throws an error if a file already exists.

There's also a [commercial Objective C library found here](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ftp-objc.asp) ($300) that might have everything you need available.  There may be other [hints available on related Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022959/cocoa-objective-c-ftp-library-framework-that-supports-mac-os-x-10-6) as well.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way i can login to my server, then not have to authenticate to upload a file?

Comment: Also, do you know of a tutorial on how to do this for mac OS?

Comment: ummm... isn't logging in the same thing as authenticating, or?

Comment: well, ha, yea, i ment can i connect on the front end, then not have to re-login if prompted to upload the file? Also, could you provide me with some sample code or something to get me started, thanks!